# How to update a stage in javafx

Tags: javafx

I expect this code that shows me a black circle in the page, then after one second it should show a white circle in the page, but it shows a blank page and after one second it shows a white circle in the page, what should I do?

```
Group group = new Group();
Scene scene = new Scene(group,200,200, Color.LIGHTGREEN);

Circle circle = new Circle(100,100,50);
group.getChildren().add(circle);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();

Thread.sleep(1000);
circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
stage.show();
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` blocks the FX Application thread, preventing it from rendering the scene. It appears from your earlier comment though that this is not what you want to do. Can you [edit] your question to explain what you *do* want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
```

And replace it with:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000),
            ae -> circle.setFill(Color.WHITE)));
timeline.setCycleCount(1);
timeline.play();
```